# Can a tree data structure be created with nodes having more than 1 incoming edge?

Tags: data-structures, recursive-datastructures

Can a tree data structure be created with nodes having more than 1 incoming edge? If not, what data structure can be used to represent such a directional structure?

Comment: By definition a tree node has at most one parent node (incoming edge).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a undirected or directed `graph` with **no cycles** for maintaining tree property. Also, for a graph to be a tree it should be `connected`. For example
Node 0 has two incoming edges.

[image]